# How to find the average of columns across tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a banking database:

I want to get the name and average balance of customers at a particular branch. That is, the average of their savings account and their checking account at branch "x".

I have tried with the query below but no success.

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_name, average_balance FROM 
(

  SELECT account_number, AVG(balance) AS average_balance
  FROM (
      SELECT account_number, balance FROM account WHERE account_number IN (SELECT account_number FROM savings_account)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT account_number, balance FROM account WHERE account_number IN (SELECT account_number FROM checking_account)
  ) AS subquery
  GROUP BY account_number
) AS subquery2 INNER JOIN customer;
```

Sample input statements:

```
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-101',  'Rock Ridge', 500000, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-101',  'Beach Lookout',  1700, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-102',  'Rock Ridge',  2465, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-103',  'Rock Ridge',  77350, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-104',  'Bargin Plaza', 480002, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-105',  'Supreme Hill', 17000, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-106',  'Rock Ridge',  5000, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-107',  'Main Sperem',  3000, '');
INSERT INTO account VALUES ('ACC-108',  'Adus Avenue',  57685, '');


INSERT INTO savings_account VALUES('ACC-101', 0.1);
INSERT INTO savings_account VALUES('ACC-102', 0.7);
INSERT INTO savings_account VALUES('ACC-103',0.6);

INSERT INTO checking_account VALUES('ACC-104', 2000);
INSERT INTO checking_account VALUES('ACC-105', 2000);
INSERT INTO checking_account VALUES('ACC-106', 2000);

INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-001',   'ACC-101',  '2012/10/13');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-001',   'ACC-106',  '2013/09/21');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-002',   'ACC-102',  '2014/08/11');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-002',   'ACC-106',  '2015/07/06');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-004',   'ACC-104',  '2016/06/11');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-005',   'ACC-105',  '2012/05/17');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-006',   'ACC-105',  '2018/10/11');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-007',   'ACC-106',  '2019/02/27');
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES ('125-233-008',   'ACC-106',  '2012/01/31');
```

I get the result below but that is not what I am looking for

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
| customer_name      | average_balance |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| Chuck Delroy       |   500000.000000 |
| Chuck Delroy       |     2465.000000 |
| Chuck Delroy       |    77350.000000 |
| Chuck Delroy       |   480002.000000 |
| Chuck Delroy       |    17000.000000 |
| Chuck Delroy       |     5000.000000 |
| Dalrymple Fayval   |   500000.000000 |
| Dalrymple Fayval   |     2465.000000 |
| Dalrymple Fayval   |    77350.000000 |
| Dalrymple Fayval   |   480002.000000 |
| Dalrymple Fayval   |    17000.000000 |
| Dalrymple Fayval   |     5000.000000 |
| Freeman Mark       |   500000.000000 |
| Freeman Mark       |     2465.000000 |
| Freeman Mark       |    77350.000000 |
| Freeman Mark       |   480002.000000 |
| Freeman Mark       |    17000.000000 |
| Freeman Mark       |     5000.000000 |
| Trisman Kemar      |     2465.000000 |
| Trisman Kemar      |    77350.000000 |
| Trisman Kemar      |   480002.000000 |
| Trisman Kemar      |    17000.000000 |
| Trisman Kemar      |     5000.000000 |
+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Example: What I am actually looking for is

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
|Delroy Chuck        | 252,500.00.     |
+--------------------+-----------------+
```

This because he would have have 500,000 in his savings account and 5000 in his checking account.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a single database tag would be really helpful.  Also an explanation of why you would want "average" rather than "sum" would help as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing expected results. Would you also please provide sample data that corresponds to this specific results, as tabular text or SQL insert statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see fields to join to customer, so I am going to assume the `account` and the `customer` table have a field `customer_number`.

First, from your original query,

```
SELECT account_number, balance FROM account WHERE account_number IN (SELECT account_number FROM savings_account)
```

can be simplified to

```
SELECT account_number, balance
FROM account
  INNER JOIN savings_account ON account.account_number = savings_account.account_number
```

What we want is to include the customer here to aggregate the average.

```
SELECT customer.customer_number, customer.customer_name, savings_account.account_number, savings_account.balance
FROM savings_account
  INNER JOIN account ON account.account_number = savings_account.account_number
  INNER JOIN customer ON account.customer_number = customer.customer_number
```

now, for the next step we union with the checking_account.

```
SELECT customer.customer_number, customer.customer_name, checking_account.account_number, checking_account.balance
FROM checking_account
  INNER JOIN account ON account.account_number = checking_account.account_number
  INNER JOIN customer ON account.customer_number = customer.customer_number
```

then this query can be aggregated with a `group by`.

before:

```
SELECT customer_name, avg(balance)
FROM
(

    SELECT customer.customer_number, customer.customer_name, account.account_number, account.balance
    FROM  account
      INNER JOIN savings_account ON account.account_number = savings_account.account_number
      INNER JOIN customer ON account.customer_number = customer.customer_number

  UNION ALL
    SELECT customer.customer_number, customer.customer_name, account.account_number, account.balance
    FROM account
      INNER JOIN checking_account ON account.account_number = checking_account.account_number
      INNER JOIN customer ON account.customer_number = customer.customer_number
) AS subquery2
GROUP BY customer_number;
```

Comment: Account has `account_number` and customer has `customer_trn`

Comment: They are joined by the `depositor` table

Comment: Well, I leave it to you to change the SQL with the information you didn't provide.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try your approach.

Comment: savings account does not have  balance field and neither does checking account. They are all stored in the account table.